# Is there a file manager in which you can sort files manually, as in Windows? or can I manually sort my files from the terminal?

Tags: 12.10, nautilus, gnome-terminal, filemanager, sort

In Nautilus you can sort files manually only in the icon view (and the arrangement is a mess). My question is: is there a file manager which you can sort files manually with, as in Windows? i.e., manually to arrange in list view, or manually to arrange in icon view without disturbing the lines.

(PS: maybe I didn't explain myself properly, in Windows I can drag a file and put it in the position that I want in the folder, in any type of view, however in Nautilus I can do it only in the icon view, and this just disturbing the lines of files. I tested Dolphin, Konqueror, PCManFM, Thunar, ROX-filer, xfe and GNOME-Commander, and they don't even have this option in icon view. And snow, thank you for your contribution but that link don't fix my problem, at the bottom there is something that seems connected but I'm a beginner and I don't understand, is this:

```
)POS is F[.C][OPTS], where F is the field number and  C the  character
   position  in  the  field.   OPTS  is one or more single-letter ordering
   options, which override global ordering options for that  key.   If  no
   key is given, use the entire line as the key.)
```

If not, can I manually sort my files from the terminal?

Comment: as I know you only nautilus can help you on this & sorting normally through the terminal means doesn't sounds good.But through the terminal sort command can help you.

Comment: whats its man page for help .http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sort

Comment: `in Nautilus I can do it only in the icon view` uh... HOW?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Nautilus can arrange files in list view:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> icon view
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> list view
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> compat view

<*_^>